# Converting dataframe to TimeSeries in Python is giving Invalid type of `time_col` error

Tags: python, time-series, data-science

I am writing Python code in Kaggle. The csv file has 8 columns in which column 0 is 'date' and column1 is 'stringency_index'

```
    series = pd.read_csv("<csv path>", 
                         na_values=['nan','?'], parse_dates = ['date'])
    series1 = series.iloc[:, [0,1]]
    series1
```

Some of the rows of series1 are:

```
    date        stringency_index

0   2020-01-29      2.78

1   2020-01-30      2.78

2   2020-01-31      2.78

3   2020-01-02      2.78

4   2020-02-02      2.78

... ... ...

716 2022-01-14      58.33

717 2022-01-15      58.33

718 2022-01-16      58.33

719 2022-01-17      NaN

720     2022-01-18      NaN
```

Then, I convert `series1` to `TimeSeries` as follows

```
series1 = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(series1, 'stringency_index')
```

I have already imported `TimeSeries` from darts. I am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: Invalid type of `time_col`: it needs to be of either 'str', 'datetime' or 'int' dtype.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: we can't run code, and we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question (not in comments)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [API doc](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.timeseries.html#darts.timeseries.TimeSeries.from_dataframe), the first argument is the DataFrame, the second argument is the name of the time column, and the third is the name(s) of the value column(s). From the shape of your data, it looks like you should call

```
TimeSeries.from_dataframe(series1, time_col='date', value_cols='stringency_index')
```

Answer (score 0):

To call the method correctly, **if you have datetime index already set in pandas dataframe**, you should use the positional `value_cols` parameter and skip `time_col` altogether.

Something like this:

`time_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(series1, value_cols = 'stringency_index')`

Otherwise it will assign `stringency_index` to `time_col` and inevitably fail because it's neither a datetime value, nor datetime index